# Does C regular expression support lookahead?

Tags: c, regex

I am trying to use regular expression in c/c++ using regex.h.
I am trying to use lookahead options, for example:

```
(?=>#).*
```

in order to extract strings after a '#'

For some reason it fails to find any matches.
Does regex.h supports lookahead/lookbehind? is there another library I can use?

I am using regex.h, on linux.

Comment: Considering that neither C nor C++ has native support for regular expressions you should probably let us know which library you are using (and when you do that, take a look at the docs for said library first).

Comment: Why use a lookahead for this in the first place? I think using a group like `#(.*)` would be the more common way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure NSRegularExpression is just a wrapper for [libicu](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp), which does support lookaheads. You have a typo in your example, right syntax is `(?=#).*` according to the link.

It doesn't really seem needed in this case though, why not just `#.*`?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's really lookbehind you're talking about, not lookahead.  That would be `(?<=#).*`, but why make it so complicated?  Why not just use `#(.*)`, as some of the other responders suggested, and pull the desired text out of the capturing group?

Also, are you really using NSRegularExpression?  That seems unlikely, considering it's an Objective-C class in Apple's iOS/MacOS developer framework.

Comment: The original question mentioned `NSRegularExpression`; the OP later edited it.

Answer (score 0):

> Does regex.h supports lookahead/lookbehind?

regex.h is not specified by standard C.  On Linux, you are likely to be using the one specified by POSIX, which implements [POSIX.2 regular expressions](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html). No, neither of the two flavors of those supports lookaround assertions.

[PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/) (Perl-compatible regular expressions) is pretty widely-used regular expression library for Unix-y systems, including Linux.  You may find it pre-installed on your Linux machine, and if not, it is very likely available via your package manager.  It's open-source, so if you must, you should be able to build it from source, too.  Being Perl-compatible, this library does support lookaround assertions.

Of course, depending on exactly what you need, you might also be able to use Perl itself, or Java, etc..